# The correlation between one variable and its coefficients produced by `lm` output

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance

Tried `cor(x1,y)` and I get a `0.09`. However, when I put the x1 in the lm model, its coefficient is negative. Does it make sense?

Comment: Was x1 the only predictor used in your lm model? Or did you include others (x2, x3, ...)?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116804/coefficient-changes-sign-when-adding-a-variable-in-logistic-regression might be of interest

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/44279/9330 could also help

Comment: @Adrian Hi, Adrian, there are other variables such as (x2,x3,...). I am just wondering should the negative number produced by `cor(y,x1)` be contradict with the positive coefficients of  x1 in `lm`.

Comment: Have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91666/sign-of-coefficients-in-linear-regression-vs-the-sign-of-correlation, it's essentially the same question as yours

Comment: Probable duplicate of the link @Adrian gave: [Sign of coefficients in linear regression vs. the sign of correlation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91666/sign-of-coefficients-in-linear-regression-vs-the-sign-of-correlation)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Adrain @Adrian