# positive and negative correlation after controlling variables

Tags: regression, correlation, regression-coefficients

i used OLS before i've include control variables i found negative association between X and Y after including  the Size i found positive association but the correlation is negative.  why this happen ?

Comment: It’s a bit difficult to determine what happened, but it sounds like Simpson’s paradox.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Positive correlation and negative regressor coefficient sign](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34151/positive-correlation-and-negative-regressor-coefficient-sign). That seems to be the same question, with the signs of the correlations and regression coefficients switched.