# Negative Binomial Regression with variable constraint?

Tags: regression, predictive-models, negative-binomial-distribution

I am working with a negative binomial regression. The data frame contains 38 predictors and 48 records. After variable selection I used only 8 variables. Finally, I got some good results.
Here is the plot of modeled versus actual data (red: Test-sample and black Train):
[image]

Now I want to go a step further: I want that all my estimated predictor coefficients (fitted by the NBGLM) stay non negative (In my model there is one variable with negative coefficient but for practical use I don't want this case).

Is there a version of the NBGLM where I can introduce thresholds for the parameter estimates?

Comment: Please provide more details and possibly a data example (raw data, plots etc.).

Comment: @Tim Hope this is edit is useful for you!

Comment: *Why* do you need the constraints? I ask because this sounds like an example of "how to lie with statistics"...

Comment: I know what you mean because I want to change something after seeing the results of modelling. The predictors describe complexity levels and the dependent variable a price. The higher the complexity, the higher the price. In practical use we want to find a model which makes sense in the way that a higher complexity goes with a higher price for all predictors. So I wanted to try a modification of the model with paramter constraints even the statistics say something different...Does it make sense?

Comment: OK, but maybe your assumptions are wrong, maybe it is not so (and the model is right)?

Comment: If I look at the Spearman Correlation of the predictor which have this negative estimate I see a positive correlation. What could be reasons for this?

Comment: See e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/116804/coefficient-changes-sign-when-adding-a-variable-in-logistic-regression

Comment: Thank you :) By the way: You prefer using only the test sample for checking predictive power or should I do cross validation also?