# Is there a phenomenon like this?

Tags: mean, simpsons-paradox

It's like the mean of every part increases, but the overall mean decrease; or the mean of a group is larger in every part but is smaller in all samples; or something like this.

I remember there is a name for this phenomenon like this (it may not be accurate) but my impression is very vague and I cannot remember it clearly.

Comment: [I think you mean Simpson’s paradox.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox)

Comment: @Dave Thank you very much, I still have a simple question. If group A has a larger mean in every part than group B but has a smaller mean overall, then which group is better? Assuming the larger the better.

Comment: I suggest posting that as a separate question that includes either a drawing or a small data set (can be made up), because I do not totally follow what you mean.

Comment: It’s like [everything’s amazing now and nobody’s happy](https://youtu.be/nUBtKNzoKZ4)

Answer (score 2):

You are thinking of (one version of) [Simpson's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simpson%27s_paradox).  You can find many threads about it on the site.

Comment: Thank you very much, I still have a simple question. If group A has a larger mean in every part than group B but has a smaller mean overall, then which group is better? Assuming the larger the better.

Comment: @user900476, you need to read through some of the threads we have on the topic. I have a related answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/78264/7290).