# When to collapse data on subject level?

Tags: mean, aggregation

I have a question about when to collapse raw data to means per unit (e.g., subjects). In my data I have the following variables:

- `id`: subject id
- `rt`: reaction time
- `type`: either A or B
- `being`: either animal, human, robot or plant

The structure of the data is that I have 100 trials per subject and each trial has an `rt`, a `type` and a `being`.

If I use two different collapsing methods, I get different values:

Method A:

I collapse my data so that I have a mean `rt` for each subject for each combination of `type` and `being`. Now I want to collapse the `being` values `human` and `robot` together and the values `animal` and `plant` together. So I add them and divide them by 2 (or use the mean function).

So I get: `MeanA_human&robot` and `MeanA_animalplant`

Method B:

I create a factor (e.g., `being_category`) which is 1 for human or robot and 2 for animal and plant, and then collapse per subject `id`, `type` and this factor.

Here I get: `MeanB_human&robot` and `MeanB_animalplant`

My problem is that `MeanA_humanrobot` is not exactly equal to `MeanB_humanrobot` (same for ..animalplant).

The differences are small, but I do not understand conceptually why there are any differences.

So basically - I think - this comes down to the question of when to collapse the data. Can someone help out here?

Comment: You have a study with reaction times for plants? My hat's off to you. Are they censored or did you wait?

Comment: Which means differ from which? Can you list them? Are your variables correlated?

Comment: I just wanted to come with descriptive factors instead of the codes in my rawdata. I thought it might simplify my problem. RTs for plants would be groundbreaking...

Comment: The means with collapsing per id, type and being and then deriving a mean for each category of being, differ from the means when I collapse per id and type directly via the being_category factor. The variables are correlated, yes.

Comment: @gung I've adjusted the post.

Comment: It would be nice to have some numbers, but given that your variables are correlated the issue is almost certainly Simpson's paradox. I have an answer here: [Basic Simpson's paradox](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/21901/7290) that might be helpful.

Comment: It was - in a way. Thank you so much. You brought me on the right track. Great. It were minor differences in `n`...